# Concatenate two consecutive foreach iterations in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have the `$result` variable. It has the following structure:
[image]

I am trying to get an array structured like this: `masculine => 1`, `feminine => 2`.

I am stuck here:

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
   foreach ($row as $column => $value)
   {
       echo $column . ' with order ' . $value . '<br/>';
   }
}
```

The output of my attempt is:

[image]

I tried using the `next()` function and apply it to the `$row` variabile, but for each iteration I got the `1(2) => false`.

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: This question's desired result doesn't align with the accepted answer, but if it is the accepted answer, then this question is clearly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP builtin function **array_column** to do this job.

> **array_column** — Return the values from a single column in the input array
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)
>
> Syntax -
>
> array array_column ( array $input , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )

And script would be like this -

```
<?php

$result = array(
    array(
        'gender_value' => 'masculine',
        'gender_preffered_order' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'gender_value' => 'feminine',
        'gender_preffered_order' => 2
    ),
);

$filtered = array_column($result, 'gender_preffered_order', 'gender_value');
print_r($filtered);
```

For more reference see the link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

**For PHP < 5.5**

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column($input, $column_key, $index_key = null) {
        $arr = array_map(function($d) use ($column_key, $index_key) {
            if (!isset($d[$column_key])) {
                return null;
            }
            if ($index_key !== null) {
                return array($d[$index_key] => $d[$column_key]);
            }
            return $d[$column_key];
        }, $input);

        if ($index_key !== null) {
            $tmp = array();
            foreach ($arr as $ar) {
                $tmp[key($ar)] = current($ar);
            }
            $arr = $tmp;
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 3):

This might work:

```
$new_array = []; // Not sure if you needed this piece but I've included it :)

foreach ($result as $row)
{
   echo $row['gender_value'].' => '.$row['gender_preferred_order'].'<br>';

   $new_array[$row['gender_value']] = $row['gender_preferred_order'];
}

print_r($new_array);
```

I highly recommend getting acquainted with [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question, but based on the result you wanted I created this:

```
$result = array(
    array(
        'gender_value' => 'masculine',
        'gender_preferred_order' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'gender_value' => 'feminine',
        'gender_preferred_order' => 2,
    )
);

$set = array();

foreach($result as $gender) {
    $set[] = array($gender["gender_value"] => $gender["gender_preferred_order"]);
}

var_dump($set); // [['masculine' => 1],['feminine' => 2]]
```